# C Error - Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token

Tags: c, pointers, swap

I'm trying to get my head around pointers and I'm trying to write a program which will swap two numbers using pointers. However, I'm getting the error as stated in the title. Here is my code:

```
    //This program swaps two numbers using pointers

#include <stdio.h>

void swap(*val1, *val2);

int main() {

    int num1, num2;
    int *pNum1, *pNum2;

    printf("Enter number 1:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter number 2:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    pNum1 = &num1;
    pNum2 = &num2;

    printf("Numbers not swapped: %d, %d\n", *pNum1, *pNum2);
    swap(pNum1, pNum2);


    return 0;
}

void swap(*val1, *val2) {

    int temp;

    temp = val1;
    val1 = val2;
    val2 = temp;

    printf("Numbers swapped: %d, %d\n", *val1, *val2);


    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(*val1, *val2);
```

should be

```
void swap(int *val1, int *val2);
```

You should then pass

```
swap(&num1,&num2);
```

If you pass a pointer then you are passing a copy of it.You need to pass the address. No need of having pointers in the calling function you can directly pass the address of the variables.

```
void swap(int *p,int *q)
{
   int t = *p;
   *p = *q;
   *q = t;

}
```

Comment: Absolutely no clue how I missed that. Thanks for the quick response!